# MATLAB: Format string array

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

I am wondering how to apply a specific format to the newly available `string array`?

```
mat = [0, 0.4, 0.2 ; 0, 0.6, 0.8]
str = string(mat)
```

I would like the resulting `string array` to show always two decimals, followed by the percent sign (such as `sprintf('%.2f%%', str)`).

How am I supposed to do that? If it's not possible with a string array, a cell array of char would be equally fine.

Comment: Loop no good ?.

Comment: @SardarUsama Well, I could do that. However, isn't there a more elegant way to solve that problem?

Comment: Your input is 2x3, do you want your str to also be 2x3 (cell array I assume) or is a 6x1 list okay?

Comment: @matlabgui It must be 2x3 cell array or string array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have ≥ R2016b, you can use [`compose`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/compose.html).

```
str = compose('%0.2f%%', mat);
```

```
str =

  2×3 cell array

    '0.00%'    '0.40%'    '0.20%'
    '0.00%'    '0.60%'    '0.80%'
```

---

For the older versions, using a loop (or `arrayfun`) is the straight-forward and elegant approach in my opinion.

```
res = arrayfun(@(x) sprintf('%.2f%%',x), mat,'un',0);
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `compose` function. It's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In instances like this a loop is generally fine, but you could do:

```
strread ( sprintf ( '%.2f%%\n', mat ), '%s', 'delimiter', '\n' )
```

But a loop is much easier to read going forward

As suggested by @SardarUsama you can also make it the same size as the original variable

```
reshape ( strread( sprintf ( '%.2f%%\n', mat ), '%s', 'delimiter', '\n' ), size(mat) )
```

P.S indeed `strread` is not recommended in the docs - but personally I find it a very useful function!! :)

Comment: reshape at the end, no?  `reshape(strread (....., size(mat))` btw the use of `strread` is not recommended by Mathworks. Mathworks recommends `textscan` instead.

Comment: true yes you could add that too! :)  Although in the comment OP said either 2x3 or array,

Comment: The OP said "cell array" or "string array" :)